# How can I reduce the time to execute this sequence of loops (possible code optimization)

Tags: list, loops, optimization, nested-loops

I am writing a conversor that reads a mesh file from gmsh and tranforms into another file extension. In some part of code I need to check a specific id, get two numbers in the line and search them into a .txt file to finally obtain the element numbers.

For example: I have the code of interest number 9 (column 4 in the file below). This is the mesh file:

1 1 2 10 1 1 7

2 1 2 10 1 7 10

3 1 2 10 1 10 8

4 1 2 10 1 8 11

5 1 2 10 1 11 9

6 1 2 10 1 9 3

7 1 2 9 3 4 17

8 1 2 9 3 17 20

9 1 2 9 3 20 18

10 1 2 9 3 18 21

11 1 2 9 3 21 19

12 1 2 9 3 19 2

13 1 2 11 4 2 22

14 1 2 11 4 22 25

15 1 2 11 4 25 23

16 1 2 11 4 23 26

17 1 2 11 4 26 24

18 1 2 11 4 24 1

19 1 2 10 5 3 27

20 1 2 10 5 27 30

21 1 2 10 5 30 28

22 1 2 10 5 28 31

23 1 2 10 5 31 29

24 1 2 10 5 29 5

25 1 2 9 7 6 37

26 1 2 9 7 37 40

27 1 2 9 7 40 38

Thus, the code 9 starts to appear in this line: 7 1 2 9 3 4 17. Once I detect this line, I also need to get the next two numbers, in this case: 3 and 4, and search them into another .txt file, like this (but with thousands of lines):

1 140 1137 946

946 1137 1138 1136

1136 1138 1139 947

947 1139 1140 1135

1135 1140 1141 948

948 1141 1142 1134

1134 1142 1143 949

949 1143 1144 1133

1133 1144 1145 950

950 1145 1146 1132

The process repeats for each line in the mesh file where I have the code of interest (thousands).

My current Python code is (the relevant part):

```
            edges = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,4]]
            for line in self.elements[1:]:
                eldata =list(map(str, line.split()))
                if code == eldata[3]: # check if the code of intereset is in the line
                    local1 = eldata[5]; local2 = eldata[6]
                    for line in elements_list:
                        tag = list(map(str, line.split()))
                        if local1 in tag and local2 in tag:
                            p1 = tag.index(local1)+1; p2 = tag.index(local2)+1
                            for e in range(len(edges)):
                                edgeTest = set([p1,p2]).issubset(edges[e])
                                if edgeTest== True:
                                    model_data.write('{' + str(index) + ','+ str(e+1) + '},\n')
                                    is_looping = False
                                    break 
                        index+=1
                        if not is_looping:
                            break 
                    index = 1 
                    is_looping = True
```

self.elements is a list with the mesh file entries and elements_list is a list that I create after read the .txt file. If the search is sucessful, I perform a final loop in the edges list to get the edge number in the element.

The current code checks 400,000 elements in approximately 2 min. I would like to obtain some suggestions to reduce this time, for instance points of optimization in this code.